# Etiquette of eating according to prophet?

Tags: sunnah

Do we need to eat with 2 finger and 1 thumb or 3 finger with 1 thumb can anyone mention any hadith related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Hadith and sirah, the biography of Prophet Muhammad rasululla salallahu alaihi wassallam, the believers, the Muslims should eat and drink only with right hand, because it is evil to eat or drink in left hand unless was is injured. The Hadith say that Satan eats and drinks in left hand.

Comment: I know that but i have read somewhere Muslim should eat with three fi ger or something like thag

Comment: @Abdullah Presumably this answers the question in the title *Etiquette of eating according to prophet?*  Questions should make it clear what the question actually is; otherwise, we end up with answers like this.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones but what about description

Comment: What do you mean by 'answers like this' Rebecca J Stones?

Comment: The author of the question appears not to care about the answer to the question in the title, but only about the question in the main text.  However, the author of this answer (presumably trying to be helpful) has answered the question in the title.  It's why it's so important to be clear on what the actual question is---otherwise we end up with answers to a question we ask, but not the question we wanted answered.